WSO2 Microintegrator: Error - Mediator from connector File not recognized
For a WSO2 Microintegrator project, I need to read a JSON file. To practice the use of the File connector (Read mediator) I did this:

Create a very simple test integration project with Connector Exporter feature
Download File connector in workspace. The Studio answers that the connector has been loaded on workspace

The code of the project is this:
<api context="/read" name="init" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/json">
        <inSequence>
            <file.read configKey="FILE_CONNECTION_1">
                <path>test.json</path>
                <readMode>Complete File</readMode>
                <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
                <enableStreaming>false</enableStreaming>
                <enableLock>false</enableLock>
            </file.read>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

As simple as a REST API that triggers a file read operation.
When export artifacts and run this on the integrated server of Integration Studio, the message
Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}file
appears and the application is undeployed. I think this problem has been already reported but no solution was given. Could it be a problem of versions of connector and server or Integration Studio?
Studio version: 8.2.0
Server version: 4.2.0 (and also 4.3.0 in external server with same result)
File connector version: 4.0.32
Some idea? Other suggested connectors?
Thanks in advance

Verify that project includes a Connector Exporter
I enter the menu Add/Remove Connector -> Remove Connector (without complete remove operation) and File was present, so I guess the connector is properly loaded.
Deploy the application in internal Studio server (version 4.2.0) and in an external server(version 4.3.0)
In both cases the error is generated and the application undeployed


@Fidel, It seems even though you have created the Connector exporter project, you have not imported the connectors to it. The connector exporter will be available in the Composite Exporter selection window only if it contains at least one connector. Therefore can you try to add the connector to the Connector exporter and try it as follows,

Right-click on the created connector exporter project, point to New and then click Add/Remove Connectors.
Select Add Connector/module and click Next. Then, click on the Workspace option. This will list down the connectors that have been imported into WSO2 Integration Studio.


For more information on packaging artifacts refer the documentation https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/develop/creating-artifacts/adding-connectors/#packaging-connectors

Sanoj, it is as you say. Now, the application is deployed. Thank you (and Arunan) for your help.

Please make sure that the ConnectorExporter is selected in the CompositeExporter module when you are exporting the CAR file / running inside the embedded Micro Integrator.


The problem is that when exporting the CAR to the integrated server, the system does not offer me the possibility of selecting Composite Exporter, as you can see in this figure:

but a Connector Exporter does exist. See project explorer menu:


Have you added the connector the Connector Exporter as well?

Arunan, I added It and everything is OK, as you can read Up here. Thank you
